# Laptop screen freezing/lagging randomly

Tags: laptop, display, freeze

I have a dell g5 5590 laptop and for about 6 months now I have been having this weird issue: the screen would randomly freeze on a frame and would come back online after moments. Sometimes it would stay frozen and I have to do something like close the lid and open it again or press Win + d (switch to desktop) or just something that would "refresh" the screen, these methods work most of the time but not always. When it is frozen, I can hear the video or the game I'm playing running fine, for all intents and purposes the laptop is actually working fine it is just the screen that's not refreshing.

I thought the problem started after a gpu driver update so I tried going back to an earlier version but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Specs:
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti

RAM: 16.0 GB

Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (Build 19042.746)

Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

Comment: Built-in screen or external monitor?

Comment: @spikey_richie Built-in screen